How to enable word-wrap (line-wrap at word boundaries) in iTerm2
After updating macOS & iTerm2, word-wrap function in iTerm2 seems to work incorrectly. Long lines break within a word instead of soft-wrapping the whole word to the next line.
Environment:

macOS version: Sonoma 14.4.1
oh-my-zsh version: 53c4c46
iTerm2 version: Build 3.4.23


Updating oh-my-zsh does not work.
How can I enable word-wrapping correctly in iTerm2?

I don't think that word wrap is controlled by iTerm2. Perhaps something in your zsh startup files is the culprit. For an experiment, do a tput smam. Do you still not see any word wrap afterwards? In addition, make sure that the shell variable COLUMNS contains the correct width of your terminal.

thx for your response! After running "tput smam", the line wrapping within the terminal still works the same way (breaking within a word). I tested COLUMNS under different window sizes, and the echoed value changes accordingly, appearing to contain the correct width.

I see that I misread your question: Actually, line wrapping works as it should.  I am not aware that zsh and/or iterm2 would have an option to do wrapping at word boundaries. It always wraps at the end of the line. With the tput command, you can just turn wrapping on and off completely.
